# Make a generic version of this asynchronous method

Tags: c#, wcf, asynchronous, silverlight-4.0, prism

I have a Silverlight client using MEF/Prism that connects to a WCF service. I am writing a "service agent" to use as a shared service throughout the application. This "service agent" is a singleton that provides the only way for the client to call the WCF service. I've implemented my service contract and all of the methods look very similar, except for the specific Begin/End operations they call and the arguments they accept.

For example:

```
public void WakeUpInstanceAsync(Foo opportunity, bool isHistorical, Action<WakeupObj> callback)
{
    if (IsOpen())
    {
        AsyncCallback asyncCallback = (e) =>
        {
            _currentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
            {
                try
                {
                    callback(_funnelClient.EndWakeUpInstance(e));
                }
                catch (CommunicationException ex1)
                {
                    // Notify someone via eventaggregator?
                    callback(null);
                }
            });
        };

        _funnelClient.BeginWakeUpInstance(opportunity, isHistorical, asyncCallback, null);
    }
}
```

Is there any way I could create a generic method that takes a 2 parameters (the "begin" method and the "end" method)?

Comment: Off topic, but based on your comment in your `catch` this might help.  You can change your `callback` parameter to `Action<Func<WakeupObj>>`.  Then `callback(() => _funnelClient.EndWakeupInstance(e))` to force the exception into whatever is calling `WakeupInstanceAsync`.  Whatever is calling this method is most likely better suited at exception handling.

Comment: @cadrell0 wow, thanks for the advice. I like that idea much better! How exactly would I call that new method? Currently, I'm calling it like `myClient.WakeUpInstanceAsync(opportunity, true, (wuObj) => _wakeUpObject = wuObj)`;

Comment: @cadrell0 nevermind, I figured out all I had to treat `wuObj` as a Func rather than an object and invoked it like `wuObj()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would something like this be what you are looking for?

```
    public void WakeUpInstanceAsync(Foo opportunity, bool isHistorical, Action<WakeupObj> callback)
    {
        this.ImplementAsyncMethod(
            asyncCallback => _funnelClient.BeginWakeUpInstance(opportunity, isHistorical, asyncCallback, null),
            asyncResult => _funnelClient.EndWakeUpInstance(asyncResult),
            callback);
    }

    public void ImplementAsyncMethod<T>(Action<AsyncCallback> begin, Func<IAsyncResult, T> end, Action<T> callback)
    {
        if (IsOpen())
        {
            AsyncCallback asyncCallback = (e) =>
            {
                _currentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        callback(end(e));
                    }
                    catch (CommunicationException ex1)
                    {
                        // Notify someone via eventaggregator?
                        callback(default(T));
                    }
                });
            };

            begin(asyncCallback);
        }
    }
```

(disclaimer - I have not compiled it)

Comment: Yeah, this is along the lines of what I was thinking of. I would love to use TPL, but I am not in a position to use a ported version for Silverlight, so I think this at least gets me started.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [TaskFactory.FromAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321543%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) to wrap nearly any `Begin`/`End` asynchronous method pair into a `Task<T>`.  This provides a much cleaner model for working with asynchronous programming, as you can then just use a continuation on the UI thread for your "callback".

Comment: I just re-tagged, to clarify that I'm using SL4...Tasks don't exist in SL4, do they?

Comment: @Ryan You could always use: http://www.perreira.net/matthieu/?page_id=172 or http://www.damonpayne.com/post/2011/02/07/Task-Parallel-Library-Ported-to-Silverlight-4.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you would need an WakeUpInstanceResult class to hold the multiple parameters.